# So what's the difference between $(x^a)^b$ and $x^{a^b}$?

Tags: exponentiation

So what's the difference between $(x^a)^b$ and $x^{a^b}$?

Particularly, why does Wolfram Alpha treat them differently?

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%5E3)%5E2

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%5E2

Comment: Well e.g $(x^5)^2 = x^{10}$ whereas $x^{5^2} = x^{25}$.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean. Because the  $(x)^2=(x^1)^2=x^{(1*2)}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\left(x^a\right)^b=x^{ab}\neq x^{a^b}$$

So the actual difference is between $\;ab\;$ and $\;a^b\;$ ....quite a difference, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

$x^{a^b}$ means: calculate $c= a^b$ and then $x^c$

$(x^a)^b$ means: calculate $c=x^a$ and then $c^b$

Answer (score 0):

$(x^a)^b$ = $x^{(a*b)}$

Whereas $x^{(a^b)}$  is  x^a^b

For example,

$(x^2)^5$ = $x^{(2*5)}$ = $x^{10}$

$x^{2^5}$ = $x^{(2^5)}$ = $x^{32}$